# Differential pair simulation on LTspice using a transmission line

Tags: ltspice, simulation, transmission-line

I'm trying to see how a long transmission line behaves by playing with its parameters in LTspice. The input signal is differential, but the output does not seem to be.

So I created the following simplified circuit to try to understand what is happening:

[image]

Here are the outputs:

[image]

Why is the common-mode voltage 0 V at the output?

Why is Vout- stuck at 0 V and not oscillating around 0 V too (like Vout+)?

Comment: part of your schematic is missing in the picture. Is vout- connected to ground? Try plotting (Vout+) - (Vout-)

Comment: No it is not. It's just another resistor

Comment: I am not sure the picture views results are ok (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be getting a 'floating nodes' error from that schematic, not sure why you're not.

The T-Line in LTspice doesn't have any DC connection from one side to the other, you might think it would work like a piece of coax but it doesn't.

Try adding a large value resistor (R=1E12) from each side of the output to ground. That appeared to solve the problem when I simulated it.

[image: t-line ltspice]

To feed the common mode voltage through you can connect the resistors across each side of the T-Line like this:

[image: t-line2 ltspice]

Comment: I don't get any "Floating node error". The trick you suggested works. I get a differential signal at the output now, but without the common mode voltage. Do you have another trick to get the DC component too? LTSpice has a "TransmissionLineInverter" simulation example for a coax cable, but I can't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @HatimB Ah, okay... return the two large resistors to Vin+ and Vin- instead of ground.
Added to answer.

Comment: I tried a solution closer to what you suggested before posting the question, but not this one. Your solution works! Thank you very much.

Comment: LTspice's topology checker is enabled by default.  It will throw a warning (shown in the error log) that the node is floating and then will automatically add a conductance to GND based on whatever the `gfloat` options parameter is set to (`1p` by default).  You can disable topology check by setting `.options topologycheck=0`, and then the circuit will get all sorts of singular matrix errors and undefined/infinite values for nodes.

Comment: How can be, in the first picture Vout- and Vout+, around 0 V?

Comment: @Antonio51, GodJihyo said that the transmission line model does not have a DC connection between its input and its output.

Comment: Ok. But I don't understand why it can't "work". Will search for the "model" and compare it with microcap v12 "Tline". Note also that when used as a "differential" system, it should be a "3-wire system" (?).

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I made a simulation (very weird, in fact).

Here is what I get (Td = 5 ns) ...

At input

[image]

At output

[image]

Comment: I don't think your impedances are matched.

Comment: Right. but OP schematic picture and others are not also (to see "something", I changed only transmission line time delay).